# How to define variable names dynamically in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

I have a name which I'd like to give to a variable, in another string variable:
`my $name = '$a';` or simply `my $name = 'a';` How to make the variable and to use it? I mean something like this (but it doesn't work):

```perl6
my $name = '$a';
my {$name} = 1; # Doesn't work
say $a; # should be 1
```

A more general case. I have a list of variable names, say `my @names = '$aa' ... '$cc';` How to declare and use the variable, whose name will be e.g. `@names[2]`?

Comment: If you want this, you're thinking wrongly about the problem. This is about Perl5, but nevertheless valid here: http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html

Comment: @Holli I wasn't thinking about using it with some hash-like data, I was just wondering how to do it. :) Thanks for the link!

Comment: This might interest you: https://docs.perl6.org/language/packages#Looking_up_names . But that's for name lookup, not declaration. I think lexical name declaration must be explicit so the compiler can check that variables exist. But when a package is imported, it can export dynamically named variables and functions. If you want to do this with a module, a recent question perl6 question by Holli has two answers that describe it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/EVAL) the lexical pad (symbol table) is immutable after compile time. Also (according to the same docs) it means `EVAL` cannot be used to introduce lexical symbols into the surrounding scope.

I suggest you use package variables, instead of lexical variable as suggested in the comments.

However, a workaround is possible: You can create your own lexical pad at run time (for the module requiring) using for example `require MODULE`:

```
my $name = '$a';
spurt 'MySymbols.pm6', "unit module MySymbols; use v6; my $name = 1; say \"\\$name = $name\"";
use lib '.';
require MySymbols;
```

**Output**:

```
$a = 1
```

Comment: @Holli Yes it is not pretty :) so this is kind of last resort if everything else fails

Answer (score 3):

Lexical scopes are immutable, but the way you would do it is `::($name)` or `MY::($name)`.

```perl6
my $a; # required or it will generate an error

my $name = '$a';

::($name) = 1;
say $a;          # 1

MY::($name) = 2;
say $a;          # 2

sub foo ($name,$value) { CALLER::MY::($name) = $value }
foo($name,3);
say $a;          # 3
```

Comment: Good idea, but the top `my $a` could be a problem? As I understood the question, the variable name `$a` should be inside another variable (meaning here: a string created on the fly), so I did not think an explicit `my $a` would be an option.

Comment: @HåkonHægland He was really asking two questions at once. The answer to if it is possible to dynamically create new variables is *no*, but the answer to how to dynamically access them is what I wrote.