# How to assign a value to a variable with a dynamically created name?

Tags: perl, dynamic-variables

I know this is a no-no...and yes, I still want to do it or at least know how to do it. I would like to set the value of a variable in Perl for which the name is dynamically created (I am looping through different arrays of strings). I know I could do it rather straightforwardly with a hash array, but I'm just curious how you do this with a scalar variable, e.g.

```
$time  = 't0';
$color = 'blue';
```

I want to create the variable

```
$bluet0 = 1;
```

I've tried

```
${time.$color} = 1
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47335538/4251338

Comment: @ssr1012, That Q&A isn't even about Perl!?

Comment: It would work except `time` is a builtin perl function. Use `${"time" . $color}` or `${"time$color"}`.

Comment: @ikegami: Really I am not understand your question. However my comment and the OP's question both are same I thought. Your opinion please?

Comment: I didn't ask any question!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```perl
${ time . $color } = 1;
```

with

```perl
no strict qw( refs );

${ $color . $time } = 1;
```

Like you said, this is [something to avoid](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html).

Comment: And just to add to ikegami's solution (thank you!), which I had tried as well and the reason why it didn't work for me was that I was also initializing my variable with `my`, i.e. `my $bluet0 = 0;` before that -- the `no strict` line gave me the hint to remove that.

Comment: Symbolic references can only reference package variables. You'd need PadWalker for lexicals.

Comment: Had wrong stricture. It's `no strict qw( refs );` that's needed. Fixed